# Run Mule Standalone Community Edition on windows 64 bit machine

Tags: mule, wrapper, java-service-wrapper

I am currently having an issue with running mule-standalone - CE-3.7.0 on a windows 64 bit machine below is the issue. I followed the [link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/soi-toolkit/wikis/IG_RT_MuleESB.wiki) here.

Update - I am using Mule 3.7.0 CE Runtime. The mule projects using JRE 8.0.

```
    Starting the Mule service...
--> Wrapper Started as Service
Launching a JVM...
Starting the Mule Container...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

WrapperJNI Error: Not licensed to use this edition of the Wrapper native library. (1)
WrapperJNI Error:  This can happen if the Wrapper binary is not the same version and edition as that of the Wrapper's JNI native library file.
WrapperJNI Error: Shutting down.
WARNING - The Wrapper jar file currently in use is version "3.2.3"
          while the version of the native library is "3.5.15-st".
          The Wrapper may appear to work correctly but some features may
          not function correctly.  This configuration has not been tested
          and is not supported.

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option PermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Using the ParNew young collector with the Serial old collector is deprecated and will likely be removed in a future release
<-- Wrapper Stopped
The Mule service was launched, but failed to start.
```

Comment: Can you check the version of Java. Is JAVA JDK is selected in build path or JRE only there in build path. Also please let me know the version of anypoint studio you are using. Regards
Srinivas

Comment: Seems you're using JRE 8 and some outdated Mule runtime, try JRE 6. But i general I suggest you to use lates Mule runtime version. Also check [this](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/1083/mule-esb-3-7-0-ce-cannot-start-with-jdk-8-in-windows-server-2012.html) thread

Comment: I am using Mule 3.7.0 CE Runtime. The mule projects using JRE 8.0 and same is updated in my question.. @nike.laos - Why i have to degrade mule project to jre 6.0 ? which means mule 3.7 CE wont support JRE 8.0 ?

Comment: @Simbu, ok then, no need to degrade to jre6. Do the following - install mule as a windows service as described [here](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/configuring-mule-as-a-windows-service). Most likely after you will face with java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load library, it is easy to fix - just create Temp folder "C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Temp\"

Comment: @Simbu, didn't my solution worked for you? I have checked it on win7 x64, mule 3.7ce and jre8

Comment: @nike apologies for late reply. No it is not worked for me. Yes i have mismatch in JRE. But still same issue persist after correcting too.

Comment: You are using the native library is "3.5.15-st" (from the Standard Edition of the Wrapper) with the Jar file "3.2.3" (from the Community Edition). You should use the files (wrapper.exe, wrapper.dll, wrapper.jar, *.bat) from the same version and edition of the Wrapper!

Answer (score 0):

To avoid such errors and start mule standalone as windows service on Windows 10 x64. I did next step:

1. Download Java service wrapper from here: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp#stable
   I choosed wrapper for Windows X86; 64bit Standard. 
   I got archive such as *wrapper-windows-x86-64-3.5.29-st.zip*
2. Download mule standalone community runtime from here:

https://repository-master.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/distributions/mule-standalone/3.7.0/mule-standalone-3.7.0.zip 
I got archive such as *mule-standalone-3.7.0.zip*

3. Unpack *mule-standalone-3.7.0.zip* to your working directoryfor example *C:\mule\mule-standalone-3.7.0* and set MULE_HOME environment variable to *C:\mule\mule-standalone-3.7.0*
4. Unpack *wrapper-windows-x86-64-3.5.29-st* and copy files from wrapper to mule standalone:
   Files *wrapper.jar, wrapper.dll* from unzipped wrapper folder *..\lib* to *C:\mule\mule-standalone-3.7.0\lib\boot*
   File wrapper.exe from folder *..\bin* to *C:\mule\mule-standalone-3.7.0\lib\boot\exec*.
5. In addition I pasted license info for trial 15 minutes key from *..\conf\wrapper-license.conf* to the end of *wrapper.conf* in mule standalone so I got such wrapper.conf ending.

```
    # Do not edit lines below!
    # This include should point to wrapper-additional.conf file in the same directory as this file
    # ATTENTION: Path must be either absolute or relative to wrapper executable.
    #include %MULE_BASE%/conf/wrapper-additional.conf
    wrapper.license.type=TIME
    wrapper.license.id=201508170000022
    wrapper.license.licensee=Tanuki Software, Ltd.
    wrapper.license.run_time=900
    wrapper.license.features=pro, 64bit
    wrapper.license.upgrade_term.begin_date=2010-06-10
    wrapper.license.upgrade_term.end_date=2016-08-17
    wrapper.license.key.1=fc1a-6a69-d210-da70
    wrapper.license.key.2=432a-e49b-1b24-6583
    wrapper.license.key.3=8947-9390-ada4-09a2
    wrapper.license.key.4=c951-ff9e-780d-1d77
```

That is it. I have wrapper worked  on trial license for 15 minutes each run.
I can install mule as Windows service  by command **mule install** and start/stop it with commands **mule start/stop**

Comment: I have followed all the steps except (File wrapper.exe from folder ..\bin to C:\mule\mule-standalone-3.7.0\lib\boot\exec.) Since i could not find wrapper.exe in bin folder.. - Error - The mule service is not installed - The specified service does not exist as an installed service. (0x424)

Comment: I checked archive wrapper-windows-ia-64-3.5.29-st.zip, which is downloaded from here: http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/download/3.5.29/wrapper-windows-ia-64-3.5.29-st.zip and it has file wrapper.exe in bin folder. So try to download wrapper from that link.